# ShellExecute opens a ms word doc as well as restores a minimised word doc

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-automation, shellexecute

I want to open MS Word docs from my app. I use ShellExecute function to do the job. It does open a word doc that I specified, but it restored a doc that I opened before and minimised, that is not what I want. Also the ShellExecute returns 42 that I don't know the meaning. Does I used the ShellExecute incorrectly?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Doc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        public static extern int ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirecotry, int nShowCmd);

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, "2.docx");
            int i = ShellExecute(this.Handle, "Edit", fileName, null, null, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is "intended behaivour" by Word (all office products) and not `ShellExecute`, open a word file and minimise it, now manually open another word file and lo and behold the first one un-minimises itself. It's something that's been bugging me personally for quite a while now but it is for all I can tell intended behaivour.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `ShellExecute` over Office automation? Do you have any arguments for that specifically?

Comment: Our app is written with Delphi 6. Delphi 6 does not support Office automation well. for example, if I use ole to open a word doc, it is minimised. So, what I may do is creating a office automation in C# and make it as a dll for the Delphi app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) doesn't let you control the application. However, you may automate Word from a C# application where you could manage the application afterwards. For example, see [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean no matter how many docs I open, it just one word app behind, so ShellExecute calls the word app and opens one doc and show all docs that were already opened?

Comment: You can't control the Word app with `ShellExecute`.